# How to check if string contains date using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js, split, fs

I have files where my logs are in multiple lines every logged event has date, I am trying to write logic
if line start with the date and
if second line dont
have date merge with first line thats the end goal, below code as first step printing lines that has dates vs no dates but it always print
else statement,
    any idea what is implement wrong ?

My question is not about validation of date Object i just want to check if string contains date any format print those lines.Issue is i want to combine multiple lines og event using date parameter.

ctrl.js

```
fs.readFile(dir + '/' + logFile, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    var line = data.split('\n');
    var messageDateInfo = line.split('|')[0].replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '');
    var d = parseDate(messageDateInfo);

    function parseDate(str) {
        var m = str.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/);
        return (m) ? new Date(m[3], m[2] - 1, m[1]) : null;
    }
    if (line.includes(d)) {
        console.log('print lines with date', line);
    } else {
        console.log('print lines without date', line);
    }
});
```

fileData

```
[2017-03-23T18:13:16Z]|verbose|bmid: n/a|infra.topicWorkers|topology changed, emitting topology event { newTopology: 
   [ '-0000001337',
     '-0000001338',
     '-0000001339',
     '-0000001340',
     '-0000001341',
     '-0000001342' ],
  oldTopology: 
   [ '-0000001337',
     '-0000001338',
     '-0000001339',
     '-0000001340',
     '-0000001341' ],
  workerId: 6,
  pid: 30488 }
[2017-03-23T18:13:16Z]|verbose|bmid: n/a|infra.topicWorkers|topology changed, emitting topology event { newTopology: 
   [ '-0000001337',
     '-0000001338',
     '-0000001339',
     '-0000001340',
     '-0000001341',
     '-0000001342' ],
  oldTopology: [],
  workerId: 4,
```

Comment: i edited my question, can you please re-open it i am really struggling on this i used answer from other question e.g `parseDate`

Answer (score 1):

You're using:

`str.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/);`

here str = `[2017-03-23T18:13:16Z]` with those square brackets `[]`,

while  `str` is in ISO date format and you are matching it with 'dd/MM/yyyy' regex that will never match

try using this regex `/^(\d{4})\D?(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\D?([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01])(\D?([01]\d|2[0-3])\D?([0-5]\d)\D?([0-5]\d)?\D?(\d{3})?)?$/`

**AND**

`new Date(m[3], m[2] - 1, m[1])` you are returning only day, month & year.

While, comparing it with `line` which has date and time i.e,`18:13:16Z` too.

You need to pass those from the array.